# Switching a Linux console serial port to normal serial port

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I have a problem when using the serial port as GPS function on Android OS.  There are no available serial ports except for the one being used for the console. So how can I configure the console serial port as a normal serial port at runtime, not by the recompiling the kernel with make menuconfig?

Comment: Not sure if you can complete do that, but would stopping console-related messages be enough?  You can try `echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829746/how-to-switch-linux-kernel-console-after-boot-process

Comment: thanks,it's very helpful.but i see another solve method via remap the console like below. i try that in own platform,and the result is fail with error open /dev/tty1 /dev/tty0.fp = open("/dev/tty1",O_RDONLY); 
ioctl(fp,TIOCCONS); 
close(fp); 
fp = open("/dev/tts/0",O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NDELAY); 
if(fp == -1) exit(0); 
tcgetattr(fp,&options); 
cfsetispeed(&options,B115200); 
cfsetospeed(&options,B115200); 
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL|CREAD); 
tcsetattr(fp,TCSANOW,&options); 
write(fp,"hello world!\n123",15); 
close(fp); 
fp = open("/dev/tty0",O_RDONLY);
ioctl(fp,TIOCCONS); 
close(fp);